# Change color for setBadgelabel Node Webkit

Tags: node-webkit, nsapplication, nsdocktile

I am currently trying to make a chat desktop application using nodeJS, angularJs, and nodewebkit.
For notifying the user, in the icon in the taskbar, I used setBadgelabel().
How can I change the color of the default badge label by the function setBadgelabel()?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't change the badge. You can only custom draw a new icon using setApplicationIconImage